# SQL- Set third column value for all query rows in select statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have been searching for a solution to my problem with no avail. I have this stored procedure that selects certain data. I was told to modify it to add a column 'Status'. Now this stored procedure selects the information for one component at a time. So say for component A: I have the query and results below:

```
 Declare @comp varchar(175)

 Select CT.ComponentPart
        CL.ComponentSupplier,
        CS.ComponentSource
 From ComponentParts CT
 inner join ComponentSource CS on CS.ComponentID=CT.ComponentID
 inner join ComponentSupplier CL on CL.ComponentTypeID=CS.ComponentTypeID
 Where CT.ComponentPart = @Comp
```

Now the results of the above query is:

---

```
        ComponentPart    ComponentSupplier       ComponentSource 
         CAF123              Supplier1                PLNT1
         CAF123              Supplier2                PLNT2
         CAF123              Supplier3                PLNT3
         CAF123              Supplier4                PLNT1
```

---

I was asked to add another column to this query called "Component Status" where if one of the PLNT's are not from a certain list then I would set the entire column value as "Obsolete" and if all the plants for that certain Component were in the list then I would set that column as "Active". Now I made a table and added that list of plants in there along with an ID field (the column names:PlntID, PLNTSource).

But the problem I am running into is I tried left joining that table in the above query and had a case statement in the select clause where if the PLNTSource field was null then set to Obsolete else Active but I cannot set the entire "status" column to one value based on the list in the query is there anyway to do that? What I am getting is below

```
Declare @comp varchar(175)

 Select CT.ComponentPart
    CL.ComponentSupplier,
    CS.ComponentSource,
    CASE
      WHEN CST.PLNtSource IS NULL
        THEN 'obsolete'
        else 'Active'
    END as 'Status'
From ComponentParts CT
inner join ComponentSource CS on CS.ComponentID=CT.ComponentID
inner join ComponentSupplier CL on CL.ComponentTypeID=CS.ComponentTypeID
left join ComponentStat CST on CST.PlNtSource=CS.ComponentSource
Where CT.ComponentPart = @Comp
```

query result:

```
    ComponentPart    ComponentSupplier       ComponentSource    Status
     CAF123              Supplier1                PLNT1         Active
     CAF123              Supplier2                PLNT2         Obsolete
     CAF123              Supplier3                PLNT3         Obsolete
     CAF123              Supplier4                PLNT1         Active
```

what result I am trying to achieve:

```
 ComponentPart    ComponentSupplier       ComponentSource    Status
     CAF123              Supplier1                PLNT1         Obsolete
     CAF123              Supplier2                PLNT2         Obsolete
     CAF123              Supplier3                PLNT3         Obsolete
     CAF123              Supplier4                PLNT1        Obsolete
```

any ideas?

Comment: Well `PLNtSource` must not be `NULL` everywhere you expect.  Check your source data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I know I want to set the entire column Status based on if there is one null value of PlntSource, so if one of the values is null I went to set the entire column of status to obsolete if there is no null then active

Answer (score 0):

Use a **temporary table**, Store the result in a temporary table with a column **status** and update the table by setting the column status to obsolete inside a if exists condition

You can use if exists condition and hardcode the value as 'obsolete' or declare a variable and make it as 'Obsoletet' or 'Active' with your condition and use it in your select statement

Comment: hello and thank you for the response, I was thinking of that option but I cannot make a temp table in that procedure based on orders but I was thinking can I do that with a function or no? and I am not sure how to update a select query column is that possible?

Comment: Hi @eto_donna You can use if exists condition and hardcode the value as 'obsolete' or declare a variable and make it as 'Obsoletet' or 'Active' with  your condition and use it in your select statement

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest the following approach, which uses a CTE to make things more readable and manageable.  Note that CTEs in SQL Server can use variables so long as they are defined within the same batch.  Since you determination of the status is the same for the entire query, we can just use a subquery to calculate this value, and then use it in your original query.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT CT.ComponentPart,
           CL.ComponentSupplier,
           CS.ComponentSource,
           CST.PLNtSource
    FROM ComponentParts CT
    INNER JOIN ComponentSource CS
        ON CS.ComponentID = CT.ComponentID
    INNER JOIN ComponentSupplier CL
        ON CL.ComponentTypeID = CS.ComponentTypeID
    LEFT JOIN ComponentStat CST
        ON CST.PlNtSource = CS.ComponentSource
    WHERE CT.ComponentPart = @Comp
)
SELECT t1.ComponentPart,
       t1.ComponentSupplier,
       t1.ComponentSource,
       (SELECT CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN t2.PLNtSource IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
                    THEN 'Obsolete'
                    ELSE 'Active' END
        FROM cte t2) AS Status
FROM cte t1
```